# Owning OTM Calls on a company that was acquired

Tags: call-options, corporate-acquisition

I own 10 $stay calls exp 7/18 but they were purchased this week and the ticker no longer exists. Am I screwed? I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 2):

When a company is acquired for cash, the expiration date is accelerated to the merger date and the options are based on the acquisition price.

If the acquisition price is above a call's strike price, you receive the intrinsic vale (acquisition price minus strike price).  If the strike price is out-of-the money, the calls expire worthless.  It's the same principle for puts (ITM vs OTM).

Traders who own ITM options receive the cash.  Those who are short ITM options deliver the cash.

For details of the OCC bulletin, google "Extended Stay America Cash Settlement/Acceleration".